# find total employees for each city/village in many related tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want count total employees in each city/village

here is with city only :

```
select r.region_name, c.country_name, l.city, count(*)
from employees e,
     departments d,
     locations l,
     countries c,
     regions r
where e.department_id = d.department_id
  and d.location_id = l.location_id
  and l.country_id = c.country_id
  and c.region_id = r.region_id
group by r.region_name,c.country_name, l.city
order by 1
```

output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlGcz.jpg

I want add a table with name 'Village' to specify employee's village

wanted output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2myFs.jpg

***But Accepted the output shows same number of employee in a village for all other village in a particular
city!***

Are there any way method to find total
Any Help

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Please refer this to learn JOIN: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: w3*ools... There must be a better reference.

Comment: Your "wanted output" image is a SQL statement.  What do you want your query output to look like?

Comment: my code"wanted output"  isn't display total employees in each village , it repeated same number in a first village to  all villages in a town and do the same for other towns !! i need the help  to solve the problem

Comment: Please share the structure of your village table.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to rewrite your SQL using JOIN-conditions:

```
select r.region_name
     , c.country_name
     , l.city
     , count(*)
from employees e
join departments d
  on e.department_id = d.department_id
join locations l
  on d.location_id = l.location_id
join countries c
  on l.country_id = c.country_id
join regions r
  on c.region_id = r.region_id
join village v
  on l.location_id = v.location_id
group by r.region_name,c.country_name, l.city, v.village_name
order by 1
```

It looks to me, like you joined the table **village** in a wrong way. You are using the *location_id* of the superior **locations**-table. If this join-condition exists, it would probably show which region etc. a village belongs to.

Take a look if there is a village_id referenced somewhere.
So, maybe your sql would give a better result, if it looked something like this:

```
select r.region_name
     , c.country_name
     , l.city
     , count(*)
from employees e
join departments d
  on e.department_id = d.department_id
join locations l
  on d.location_id = l.location_id
join countries c
  on l.country_id = c.country_id
join regions r
  on c.region_id = r.region_id
join village v
  on ??.village_id= v.village_id
group by r.region_name,c.country_name, l.city, v.village_name
order by 1
-- please replace the ?? with the letter of the table where the village is referenced. This coud be c, l or r.
```